# Mutliple event's to listen for in a input element (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, reactjs

Hello I have a input element something like this:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  className="form-control" 
  placeholder="Search for..." 
  value={this.state.text} 
  onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
```

I have button beside it that basically `onClick` would make an ajax call using the input text to get the search results.

What I want to do is not only for click event but also on pressing enter the ajax call should go through so I tried something like this:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  className="form-control" 
  placeholder="Search for..." 
  value=this.state.text} 
  onChange={this.handleTextChange} 
  onKeyDown={this.handleEnter} />
```

But it seizes to work any ideas's why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `e.preventDefault`

```
handleEnter: function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var text = this.state.text.trim();
    if(!text){
      return;
    }

    this.props.onTextChange({ text: text });
  }
},

handleTextChange: function (e) {
  this.setState({ text : e.target.value });
},
```

[`Example`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxqYVv?editors=0010)

Comment: why does e.preventDefault() make's it to stop working?

Comment: @Varenya `e.preventDefault()` removes default browser behaviour, so in this case for `onKeyDown` it is enter new text to input. That's why when you added `preventDefault` to `onKeyDown` you can't not enter any text to input